# what is the wp7 pivot control equivalent in windows 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, pivotviewer

i am looking for the wp7 pivot control equivalent for a win 8 app.. for xaml based c# implementation of certain tabbed sections of data.. please let me know if it is available..

if not, what other controls come close to it?

Same question asked [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/winappswithcsharp/thread/ce78ea55-7696-4a7d-9549-68c36c2973c4) someone before. But no good response yet

**EDIT**: In Microsoft music player in win 8 consumer preview , you can see a tabbed view .That is exactly what I want. I don't want to use Fly out control for this.

Comment: No pivot. Your are on your own. I've seen custom tabbed control implemented in the metro apps and it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented a pivot control in my library. See https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/MtPivot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the "Cloud" "Downloaded" tab switch in Kindle App and the "DOW" "S&P500" "NASDAQ" tab switch in Finance App.

I don't think there is any controls like that. In my own experience, I use a `div` to pretend to be a tab and update the main view (in my case, `GridLayout`) when I switch "tab". I don't think `FlipView` is what you want either because they are essentially not tab.

If you still keep the old Developer Preview samples, you can find the source code of the Conference App (i.e. the /Build// App). Their "schedule" page has similar "tab" control too. But I looked into the source code once and couldn't find anything useful (that was a few month ago). So good luck with that. :P

It is hard to believe that they don't have a "tab" control, but I couldn't find anything like "tab" in their [Control List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465453.aspx). Especially when they had `Pivot Control` in WP7.

Answer (score 0):

I found something like this. `Pivot`, `Filters`, `Sort` and `View` options are available in a hub page.

Details are given in this [Blog](http://blog.ilink-systems.com/SitePages/Windows8-and-Metro-UI.aspx). Hope it helps somenbody! :)